# What is the MRTK v2 equivalent to UAudioManager from HTK?

Tags: mrtk

I'm porting my app from HoloToolkit 2017.4.3 to Mixed Reality ToolKit v2 (RC1 - refresh). My current app has a UAudioManager component on one of the elements in my scene. I can't seem to find the functional equivalent in MRTKv2. Is there one?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no equivalent to UAudioManager in MRTKv2, however there is a branch [feature/mrtk_audiomanager2](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/commits/feature/mrtk_audioManager2) that joekellyms was working on.

I believe that you could copy the UAudioManager code from feature/mrtk_audiomanager2 branch, or just directly copy the code for UAudioManager from HoloToolkit into your project.